Why do the British and American editions of Poirot Investigates differ?
The collection Poirot Investigates was published in Britain in 1924 and the United States in 1925. As the table of contents for each edition shows, the American edition includes three stories that are not in the British: "The Veiled Lady," "The Lost Mine," and "The Chocolate Box." Looking up these stories in the Agatha Christie wiki on fandom reveals that they were originally published in The Sketch magazine in 1923, as were the other stories in the collection.
So, why were these three stories left out of the British edition? They were not republished in Britain until 1974, in Poirot's Early Cases. What would account for the initial omission and the long gap before their subsequent reappearance in a British collection?
